# How to keep long ajax requests running even if i refresh the page?

Tags: php, ajax, server

i have a long ajax request so it still do things for 5 min for example, but i want to run it on the server proccess, so i want to find it still working  when i refresh The page.
Thank you

Comment: Tell PHP to ignore user abort `ignore_user_abort(true);` http://php.net/ignore_user_abort

Comment: i'll try , thank you